# How to check if the client is still connected in exceptionCaught of Netty server?

Tags: exception, netty

My Netty server sends back an error response to the client from my exceptionCaught method on the ChannelHandler. If the client has disappeared, this causes an infinite recursion. Here's the stack trace snippet:

```
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:778) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCode(AbstractNioWorker.java:501) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:129) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:66) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:733) [netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:694) [netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at com.inversoft.cleanspeak.store.content.server.netty.ContentStoreChannelHandler.exceptionCaught(ContentStoreChannelHandler.java:68) ~[cleanspeak-content-store-2.3.jar:2.3]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.exceptionCaught(FrameDecoder.java:378) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:533) [netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:790) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCode(AbstractNioWorker.java:501) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:129) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:66) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:733) [netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:694) [netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at com.inversoft.cleanspeak.store.content.server.netty.ContentStoreChannelHandler.exceptionCaught(ContentStoreChannelHandler.java:68) ~[cleanspeak-content-store-2.3.jar:2.3]
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.exceptionCaught(FrameDecoder.java:378) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:533) [netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:790) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCode(AbstractNioWorker.java:501) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:129) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:66) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:733) [netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:694) [netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
```

My question is, what is the best way for me to test if the client is still there in my exceptionCaught method? Does e.getChannel().isOpen() work?

Answer (score 1):

You can check with channel.isConnected() but this may not work out as writes are asynchronous and so it may not be true anymore when the actual write happens. What I most of the times to is something like that:

```
Channel channel = ...
channel.write(data).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
```

This will ensure that the channel is closed after the write attempt.

Comment: We can't close the Channel because we use persistent connections to the server. Perhaps I need to rethink that decision though. I'm worried that the connection overhead will crush my performance.

Comment: You don't need to close a channel.  As Norman said, you can check if the channel is connected using `Channel.isConnected()`.  For TCP sockets, `Channel.isOpen()` should also work.

Comment: @TrustinLee that's what I figured, but Norman's reply made it sound unreliable. I'll roll with that solution for now.